# What's the meaning & relevance of LIC logo "yogakshemam vahamyaham"?

Tags: scripture, philosophy, identification-request, sanskrit, terminology

What's the philosophy of *"yogakshemam vahamyaham"*  & how is it relevant to LIC (Life Insurance Corporation of India)?

> अनन्याश्चिन्तयन्तो मां ये जना: पर्युपासते | तेषां नित्याभियुक्तानां योगक्षेमं वहाम्यहम्
>   BG 9.22 - Those persons who, becoming non-different from Me and meditative, worship Me everywhere, for them, who are ever attached (to Me), I arrange for securing what they lack and preserving what they have.

Comment: A commercial enterprise trying to gain customers by using religious reference is tamasic and not worth comment.

Comment: "sattva.rajas,tamas" are only poetry and mean nothing l\in real life.

Comment: 'how is it relevant to LIC' - this is still off-topic.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ***Q.*** *What's the source and meaning of this verse?*

Srimad Bhagavad Gita is the source of this verse:

> अनन्याश्चिन्तयन्तो मां ये जनाः पर्युपासते।
> तेषां नित्याभियुक्तानां **योगक्षेमं वहाम्यहम्**।।9.22।।

And [here are some useful translations](https://www.gitasupersite.iitk.ac.in/srimad?language=dv&field_chapter_value=9&field_nsutra_value=22&ecsiva=1&etsiva=1&etpurohit=1&etgb=1&setgb=1&etssa=1&etassa=1&etradi=1&etadi=1&choose=1):

- English Translation By Swami Adidevananda

  > 9.22 There are those who, excluding all else, think of Me and worship Me, aspiring after eternal union with Me. **Their prosperity and welfare (Yoga and Ksema) are looked after by Me.**
- English Translation By Swami Gambirananda

  > 9.22 Those persons who, becoming non-different from Me and meditative, worship Me everywhere, for them, who are ever attached (to Me), **I arrange for securing what they lack and preserving what they have.**
- English Translation By Swami Sivananda

  > 9.22 For those men who worship Me alone, thinking of no other, for those ever-united, **I secure what is not already possessed and preserve what they already possess.**

For deep interpretation you may go with commentaries of Shankara, Ramanuja etc.

Now, taking about "how is it relevant with LIC" sounds partially off-topic or opinion-based. Though it is obvious that it should be analogous like:

BG: For those men who worship Me alone, thinking of no other, for those ever-united
LIC: Those who regularly pay instalments/premium!

Yogakshemam Vahamyaham:

BG: I secure what is not already possessed and preserve what they already possess.
LIC: We Secure the value of paid instalments/premium and *equivalent value of your life* after the life!

Comment: If you think that your answer is Not off-topic, then kindly cast your vote for reopen.